# Does anyone have a hypothesis at how Instana can avoid sampling and process 100% of traces

Tags: monitoring, instana

Most APM solutions which analyze and store traces will sample traces to manage the volume of traces stored/analyzed (millions per day!).

Instana claims to store and analyze all traces without sampling. I have been doing some research around Instana, but do not see any whitepaper/blog post that hints at how they accomplish this. Wondering if there is a whitepaper / seminar I have missed that may have hinted at this.

For example, Lightstep has a similar claim and does so through its satellite architecture - they provide a high level explanation of how they try and capture 100% of traces (temporarily).

Does the community here have any good hypothesis - high level - how Instana approaches the challenge?